# Recharts and Rollup - ResponsiveContainer/ResizeObserver issue

Tags: rollup, recharts

When I go to render my plot that was built with Rollup, I get the following error.
I only seem to be having issues with the ResponsiveContainer component. If I remove that from the project, everything works as expected.

The only thing I could find is some people are suggesting a polyfill, but there should be no reason I need one since I'm not really doing anything out of the ordinary?

Any pointer would be super appreciated! Thanks!

Update: I tried installing 1.8.5 and everything worked.
Would still like to get the 2.x working though.

The Error:

```
TypeError: Failed to construct 'ResizeObserver': 
Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

React Code:

```
    <div style={{ width: '300px', height: '300px', userSelect: 'none' }}>
      <ResponsiveContainer width={700} height="80%">
        <AreaChart
          width={500}
          height={300}
          data={data}
          margin={PLOT_MARGIN}>
          ...
        </AreaChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
```

Rollup Config:

```
  // // UMD
  {
    input,
    output: {
      file: packageJSON.browser,
      format: 'umd',
      sourcemap: true,
      name: 'my-package-name',
      globals: {
        react: 'React',
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      }),
      external(),
      nodeResolve({ extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.node'] }),
      commonjs(),
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, it seems to be fixed in 2.1.12.
https://github.com/recharts/recharts/pull/2820

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! Found an earlier version of 2.x that it worked on. Will try out 2.1.12 when I have a sec!